# How to ignore nested enums from mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have several reference entities with nested enums for convenience. For example:

```
public class StatusA
{
    public enum Values
    {
        Active = 1,
        Inactive = 2,
        InProgress = 3
    }
}

public class StatusB
{
    public enum Values
    {
        Sent = 1,
        Accepted = 2,
        Expired = 3
    }
}

public class EntityA
{
    public StatusA.Values Status {get; set;}
}

public class EntityB
{
    public StatusB.Values Status {get; set;}
}
```

I'm getting the following exception at the time of model configuration: *The type 'StatusA+Values' and the type 'StatusB+Values' both have the same simple name of 'Values' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.*

Trying to fix it I found out that NotMappedAttribute is not applicable to enums. I also tried fluent API `.Ignore<T>` (which also requires ref type, not enum) and `.Ignore(IEnumerable<Type>)`, but no luck. Google search was also not very helpful.

Is there any other way to exclude those enums from model?

Comment: tried private not public ?

Comment: Thanks, but they have to be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only get the enumeration type in your model if you actually include a property of that type. If you do that, there *cannot* be any way of ignoring the type, without also ignoring the property. And testing shows that ignoring the property is sufficient to also ignore the type.

Here's a minimal complete test program to get the exception you're getting:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public E P { get; set; } // #1

    public enum E { }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public E P { get; set; } // #2

    public enum E { }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder(DbModelBuilderVersion.Latest);
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>();
        var model = modelBuilder.Build(new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2012"));
    }
}
```

It should be obvious that as long as #1 and #2 are both part of the model, you cannot avoid mapping the enumeration types. And if you remove either #1 or #2 (or both), or mark *them* with the `NotMapped` attribute, you will see that you no longer get the exception you're getting now.

You *may* be able to avoid renaming the enumeration type if you can avoid mapping a property of that type, like so:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PAsInt { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public E P {
        get { return (E) PAsInt; }
        set { PAsInt = (int) value; }
    }

    public enum E { }
}
```

This was the old approach which was required back when EF didn't support enumeration types at all. Unfortunately, this approach does mean that a query `context.As.Where(a => a.P == E.C)` won't work, because the model doesn't know about the `P` property. It would need to be written as `context.As.Where(a => a.PAsInt == (int)E.C)`. Depending on your needs, it may be good enough, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, I have those properties (enum types) in my model. I also updated the question to reflect this. Unfortunately I need to map those properties, they need to be persisted in db. So far the only solution i see is to give those enums different names. Is there any other option?

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of this usage of `DbModelBuilder`. Nice for demonstration purposes!

Comment: @Jk_xp There is, and I've updated my answer. It will sometimes be a good choice, and sometimes be a bad choice, so I cannot tell whether it will be acceptable to you.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. If you're interested, you can follow it up with `var compiledModel = model.Compile(); var objectContext = compiledModel.CreateObjectContext<ObjectContext>(new SqlConnection());` to test SQL generation too: `Console.WriteLine(((ObjectQuery)objectContext.CreateObjectSet<A>().Where(a => a.Id == 3)).ToTraceString());` (I probably made a mistake in the syntax somewhere, but you should get the idea.)

Comment: @hvd Thanks, I called persisted property "StatusId", and actual enum "Status" and I think it will work for me.